# Как адаптировать фоновое изображение чтобы оно не обрезалось?

Tags: css, scss, hmtl

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

чтоб подстраивалось под разрешение экрана

```
.promo{
min-height: 650px;
padding: 21px 0 93px 0;
background: url("../../img/main.jpg") center center / cover no-repeat;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так

```
.promo{
    background: #000 url("../../img/main.jpg");
    -moz-background-size: 100%; /* Firefox 3.6+ */
    -webkit-background-size: 100%; /* Safari 3.1+ and Chrome 4.0+ */
    -o-background-size: 100%; /* Opera 9.6+ */
    background-size: 100%; /* modern browsers */
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

Comment: Как там? Работает?

Comment: пока подстраиваю, вроде все работает, спасибо!

Comment: Есть хороший сайт htmlbook.com. Там много полезного. Он вам поможет.

Comment: Спасибо большое!